# How to control the jquery keydown events execution binded for different dom elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown

iam trying to fix a bug in my project,
i have two methods binded to keydown handler for different locators.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
      // block of code executes when e.which === 13
      }); ---------- this is one handler1

$(".some_class").keydown(function(e){
      // block of code executes when e.which === 13
      }); ---------- this is second handler2 which was binded on specfic class (tab) in html dom.
```

when enter key was pressed on that tab , second handler2 is executing first and later handler1.

I need handler1 to be executed first.
Do we have any property/attribute so that handlers binded on document gets executed first?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes.  Look into [event bubbling and capturing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing-in-javascript).

Comment: thanks @James , it worked using document.addEventListener('keydown',callback,true), i though of using capturing in jquery but jquery is not supporting , so went with js